# Extender el modelo AbstractUser en Django

Tags: python, django

estoy siguiendo un video de como extender dicho modelo, pero no me pasa del
makemigrations con diferentes errores.

autenticacion-->models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from pais.models import Paises


# Create your models here.

class navegante(AbstractUser):
    # username = email
    # email = email2
    cif_nif = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    pais = models.ForeignKey(Paises,models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    tlf1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    tlf2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    denominacion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contacto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #contrato = models.ForeignKey(ContratoCliente,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=False,null=False)
    inicio_comunicacion = models.DateTimeField()
    fin_comunicacion = models.DateTimeField()
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'autenticacion',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'autenticacion.navegante'
```

autenticacion-->admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import navegante


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(navegante)
```

si hago makemigrations. Este error:

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: blog.Post.autor: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with
> the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
> HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

Si comento AUTH_USER_MODEL:

```
#AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'autenticacion.navegante'
```

Este otro:

> d:\webs\ProyectoWeb>python manage.py makemigrations SystemCheckError:
> System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: autenticacion.navegante.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor
> 'Group.user_set' for 'autenticacion.navegante.groups' clashes with
> reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'autenticacion.navegante.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
> autenticacion.navegante.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse
> accessor 'Permission.user_set' for
> 'autenticacion.navegante.user_permissions' clashes with reverse
> accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'autenticacion.navegante.user_permissions' or
> 'auth.User.user_permissions'. auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse
> accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse
> accessor for 'autenticacion.navegante.groups'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'autenticacion.navegante.groups'.
> auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor
> 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with
> reverse accessor for 'autenticacion.navegante.user_permissions'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or
> 'autenticacion.navegante.user_permissions'.

No sé lo que hace en el video (1BeZxMbSZNI) que yo no haga. He estado mirando las preguntas similares, pero son antiguas y desde mi, mas complejas de lo que estoy intentando. Poco a Poco.
¿Donde puedo estar comentiendo el error? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta linea esta marcando el origen del error.

> ERRORS: blog.Post.autor: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'

El modelo Post esta relacionado con User (Que es un modelo personalizado) en el campo autor y dicha relación la puedes declarar importando desde settings

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
      # tus otras propiedades
    )
    # ...tus otros campos
```

Comment: Gracias, era eso.